# Keep Parent from Scrolling While iframe is Focused

Tags: iframe, scroll, window, parent

When a page is focused on an iframe, and the iframe is not scrollable or has fully scrolled in a particular direction, Webkit browsers and Opera will then scroll the parent when using arrow keys or spacebar to scroll. This occurs despite the iframe remaining focused. I do not want the parent window to scroll in this situation.

Below, I have included an example page where you can test the issue. If you click the iframe, then use your down arrow key to scroll down to the end of the Microsoft page, the parent page will then scroll until you release the arrow key or until you reach the end of the parent page.
[Test Page](http://www.webdevout.net/test?0s&raw)

This occurs in Chrome, Opera, and Safari, but does not occur in IE and Firefox. Anyone know a method to prevent the parent from scrolling in this situation?

Comment: I know this is super old, but did you ever find a solution?